# Why should I add things to the /lib directory over /config/initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Functionally speaking, it seems like adding a new file to these locations has the same effect **except** files added to `/config/initializers` are automatically `required`. Given this advantage, is there any reason to add files to `/lib`?

Are there any other differences between these two folders?

Comment: Is that necessarily an advantage? You really don't want to require more than you need.

Comment: Why not? The overhead of requiring something is pretty low and is only paid when my app starts (right?). OTOH, the overhead of having to remember to require something is decently high (proof: I frequently forget to require the modules I need!)

Answer (score 2):

`config/initializes/` is for things you want loaded when you app loads hence 'initializer'.

As for `lib/` you want to add your tasks such as rake files, cron jobs, etc.

You can think of it like this: initializes are self contained and don't get called where as the library contains things that get called.